# Unable to use kafka jars on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using spark structured streaming to read data from single node Kafka. Running below setup locally on mac. I can read via spark-submit, but does not work in Jupyter notebook.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,from_json
from pyspark.sql.types import  StructType, StructField, StringType, LongType, DoubleType, IntegerType, ArrayType

import time
spark.stop()
time.sleep(30)

spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .appName('KafkaIntegration6')\
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.4")\
    .getOrCreate()
print('done')

kafka_stream_df = spark\
    .readStream\
    .format("kafka")\
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")\
    .option("subscribe", "TestTopic2")\
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")\
    .load()
```

**Error**: AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide.

**Question**: Im able to run same code, can read from Kafka, using spark submit by passing spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.4 as --packages. However when I try to run from Jupyter notebook by importing Kafka package during session creation, getting this error. When looking at spark web UI on http://localhost:4040/environment/, I can see package org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.4 mentioned under spark.jars.packages

Comment: It should be `3.4.0` or `3.4.1`... `3.4` doesn't exist, so shouldn't work with `--packages` either. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12/3.4.0

Comment: fwiw, it does work in Jupyter, so that's not the issue. See  https://github.com/OneCricketeer/docker-stacks/blob/master/hadoop-spark/spark-notebooks/kafka-sql.ipynb

Comment: sorry, I  was using 3.4.1 on spark-submit which was working fine. Now tried with spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.4.1 in above code during session creation on Jupyter, running into same error.

Comment: I referred to your code https://github.com/OneCricketeer/docker-stacks/blob/master/hadoop-spark/spark-notebooks/kafka-sql.ipynb earlier when I tested all these, works fine only in spark-submit, does not work on Jupyter, running into same issue of 'Failed to find data source: kafka' on Jupyter

Comment: Hmm. I just tested with Spark 3.4.1, and I am getting the same. When I ran it before, there were logs that it was actually downloading the JARs from Maven Central, but I dont see that at all this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This alternative method still seems to be working

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import os

scala_version = '2.12'  # TODO: Ensure this is correct
spark_version = pyspark.__version__

packages = [
    f'org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_{scala_version}:{spark_version}',
    'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.5.1'
]

args = os.environ.get('PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS', '')
if not args:
    args = f'--packages {",".join(packages)}'
    print('Using packages', packages)
    os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = f'{args} pyspark-shell'
else:
    print(f'Found existing args: {args}') 

spark = SparkSession.builder\
   .master("local")\
   .appName("kafka-example")\
   .getOrCreate()
```

In the logs, I get this, which I was not seeing when using `spark.jars.packages` (which should work, according to docs)

```
Using packages ['org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.4.1', 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.5.1']
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/private/tmp/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/jars/ivy-2.5.1.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
Ivy Default Cache set to: /Users/jomoore/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /Users/jomoore/.ivy2/jars
org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12 added as a dependency
org.apache.kafka#kafka-clients added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-27575234-cd3f-4e23-9c25-4ea0f1309b35;1.0
    confs: [default]
    found org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.4.1 in central
    found org.apache.spark#spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.4.1 in central
    found org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-client-runtime;3.3.4 in central
    found org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-client-api;3.3.4 in central
    found org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.1.10.1 in local-m2-cache
    found org.slf4j#slf4j-api;2.0.6 in central
    found commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.3 in local-m2-cache
    found com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;3.0.0 in local-m2-cache
    found org.apache.commons#commons-pool2;2.11.1 in local-m2-cache
    found org.apache.kafka#kafka-clients;3.5.1 in local-m2-cache
    found com.github.luben#zstd-jni;1.5.5-1 in local-m2-cache
    found org.lz4#lz4-java;1.8.0 in local-m2-cache
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12/3.4.1/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.4.1.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.4.1!spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12.jar (195ms)
downloading file:/Users/jomoore/.m2/repository/org/apache/kafka/kafka-clients/3.5.1/kafka-clients-3.5.1.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.kafka#kafka-clients;3.5.1!kafka-clients.jar (11ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12/3.4.1/spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.4.1.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.spark#spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.4.1!spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12.jar (117ms)
```

Comment: thank you. Above alternative method works fine in Jupyter python notebook, not on Jupyter pyspark notebook. Getting same error 'Failed to find data source: kafka' on pyspark. Noticed similar behaviour when I was trying to import delta packages last week, works in python shell/notebook, also works with spark-submit , but not in 'pyspark' shell/notebook. Is this expected behaviour? what could be the reason for this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "pyspark notebook"? Jupyter module is the same between any interpreter, but running pyspark or spark-submit will pre-evaluate all arguments and environment variables, so defining config/PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS via code wouldn't work, if I understand correctly; you'd need to modify spark-conf ahead of time, or export env vars before running them

Comment: when we try to launch a new jupyter notebook, it prompts asking python or pyspark  or R or Toree-Scala. So when I choose python jupyter all good, not with pyspark jupyter notebook. Wondering why it was not working as mentioned above with pyspark jupyter notebook?

Comment: If you used Toree, then that sets up the kernelspec such that the `if not args` statement in my answer won't run since it pre configures the args

Comment: I'm using pyspark notebook on Jupyter not Toree.

Comment: Toree installs the "pyspark" kernel. Just running `pip install jupyter pyspark` doesn't do that. That's why using the "python" one works fine

Answer (score 0):

Update the following in the bash profile.

```
alias pnotebook='pyspark --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.0 '
```

Open your notebook as follows:

```
pnotebook
```

Comment: This starts a shell, not a jupyter notebook (unless you set another env var), and did you test this? I think you still need kafka-clients

Comment: Sorry. It has to be done after you configured Jupyter. Anyway I wrote an article on the complete set up extracted from my training's lab. You can refer from the following link.https://medium.com/@lifeskolur/ttp-series-enabling-pyspark-in-jupyter-and-integrating-kafka-jars-7a0456adf88c

Comment: The order doesn't really matter, as shown in my answer 1) I suggest using Python 3.10 or 3.11 at least 2) Pip comes with Python, don't need to wget a script 3) when pip is used to get pyspark, it's currently 3.4.1